# how recursion uses stack in php

Tags: php, recursion

i want to know how recursion uses stack, so that i can know what happens when recursion ends. Do script goes to stack and perform operations that were left to execute because of recursion or it continues script execution from next line...

Comment: Be aware that PHP only supports 100 layers of recursion.  That is, a function that call itself, or a function that calls another function that calls the original (a -> b -> a -> ...) can only go one hundred levels deep.  Once this cap is hit, the script will terminate with an uncatchable fatal error.

Comment: @Charles: hehe amazing. Does that happen with recursive functions only or will "f1 -> f2 -> ... -> f99 -> f100 -> f101" fail as well?

Comment: @Martinho, good question.  I created 200 functions, each calling the previous.  It died with the same error after a depth of 100.  Looks like this limit isn't recursion-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When recursion ends, execution continues at the next line after the first call to the recursive function, as it would with any other function call. A recursive function is a function like any other, except at some point during the function's execution, it calls itself again.

Comment: yah but in PHP5 i have called a function for making TreeView with mysql and php i got amazed with php stacking ability...